# Trouble with VPN Tunnel

Tags: vpn, udp

How to direct a UDP Packet through a VPN tunnel?

The router in question dose not have any features that would allow a UDP flooding or broadcasting, so for this project I am shooting in the dark, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cross-post.  http://superuser.com/questions/578115/how-to-direct-a-udp-packet-through-a-vps-tunnel

Comment: When I made them I had no idea they were connected, a mistake on my part, I apologize for that.  Honestly thought these were unconnected sites, was looking for as much insight as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way you'd direct *any* traffic through a VPN. You ensure that your IP routing rules point the desired traffic through the tunnel.

Also, ensure that traffic is permitted through any firewalls along the path.